# Htaccess rewrite in Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

i'm trying to remove a certain string ".html" from our urls

current example url:

http://www.buildingmaterialsonline.com.au/insulation/by-brand/pink-batts/l/price-6,10///.html?dir=asc&order=price

to:

http://www.buildingmaterialsonline.com.au/insulation/by-brand/pink-batts/l/price-6,10///?dir=asc&order=price

my current htaccess file is :

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

#If request contains ref param
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?([^&\ ]+).html=  [NC]  
#redirect to URL without the html param
RewriteRule ^  %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=301] 

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use htaccess to do this.

Magento has an option in the back end to add these suffixes. It's .html by default.

This article goes through how to change it:

http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-remove-html-from-magento/

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple option provided by Magento to remove .html from Category and Product URLs.

You don't need to any thing with .htaccess.

Go to System --> Configuration

Then Click on Catalog in Left Menu.

Then under "Search Engine Optimizations" tab, remove ".html" from "Product URL Suffix" and "Category URL Suffix".

Click on "Save Config" button.

Note: If you want you can set any other suffix for these entries.